# Testing Android apps (games)

Tags: android, google-play, android-testing

I have recently built a game and published it on the Google Play Store. I am not a company and I do not have a large range of devices to test it on. So I was wondering if anyone knows the best way to test Android apps. Maybe there is a forum or website that allows people to share their own new apps?

Answer (score 1):

The Android framework includes an **integrated testing framework** that helps you test all aspects of your application and the SDK tools include tools for setting up and running test applications. Whether you are working in Eclipse with ADT or working from the command line, the SDK tools help you set up and run your tests within an emulator or the device you are targeting.

The Android testing API is based on the JUnit API and extended with a instrumentation framework and Android-specific testing classes.

References: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/index.html
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html
http://developer.android.com/training/testing.html

Comment: The virtual device part yes. I have tried that which works great was just looking for a type of forum so I could get a response like comments and such from people since getting noticed on play store I am guessing is rather hard

Comment: If you'd like to get your apps tested by real people, you might want to check http://www.usertesting.com/ and plenty of other similar services. You'll get a video (with audio) of your target market using your app.

Comment: Sort of what I'm looking for. Really nice find thanks, though the pricing seems a tad excessive.